# How to display the Time in and out of bio metric device horizontal in mysql?

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to display the data from a log file to mysql database in php file horizontal.

Here is my design table:

```
EmpID | DATE               | STATUS           |
8636   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM AM   0
8636   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM PM   1          
8636   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM PM   0
8636   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM PM   1
```

So I want to display this table by horizontal in php or in mysql query.

Like this:

```
EmpID | TIME IN            | TIME OUT           |
8636   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM AM   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM PM
8636   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM PM   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM PM
```

Here's my code 
"SELECT `attendancelog`.EmpID,
(Case When `attendancelog`.status = '0' Then `attendancelog`.Date_time END) as 'Time_In',
(Case When `attendancelog`.status = '1' Then `attendancelog`.Date_time END) as 'Time_Out'
FROM `attendancelog`
GROUP BY `attendancelog`.Date_time

Here's the result

```
EmpID | TIME IN              | TIME OUT           |
8636   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM AM   NULL
8636   NULL                  YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM PM          
8636   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM PM   NULL
8636   NULL                  YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM PM
```

Comment: I  already did the union and group by but the result is just the same .
SELECT `EmpID`,
(Case When `Status` = '0' Then `Date_time` END) as 'Time_In'
FROM `attendancelog` 
WHERE `EmpID` = '8636' AND `Date_time` LIKE '%2018-07-09%'
GROUP BY `Date_time`

UNION ALL

SELECT `EmpID`,
(Case When `Status` = '1' Then `Date_time` END) as 'Time_Out'
FROM `attendancelog` 
WHERE `EmpID` = '8636' AND `Date_time` LIKE '%2018-07-09%'
GROUP BY `Date_time`

Comment: Can you please do a `var_export()` of your query result and add it to your post.

Comment: And can you please _NOT_ post code in the comments, hard to read, no highlighting etc. Edit your question and paste the code (with relevant information) there. Thx

Comment: Your question title and tags specifically included PHP, and that’s where I would suggest you tackle this ... You don’t have anything to properly GROUP BY here as far as I see, and creating one “cumulative” record out of several individual ones without a proper grouping criterion is rather complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already did it by using this query.

```
"SELECT `recno`,`EmpID`, `LocID`, CAST(`Date_time` as Date) Check_date,
MIN((CASE WHEN  CAST(`Date_time` as TIME) BETWEEN '07:00:00' AND '11:59:00' THEN CAST(`Date_time` as TIME) END))'TIMEIN1',
MIN((CASE WHEN  CAST(`Date_time` as TIME) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '12:30:00' THEN CAST(`Date_time` as TIME) END))'TIMEOUT1',
MIN((CASE WHEN  CAST(`Date_time` as TIME) BETWEEN '12:31:00' AND '13:30:00' THEN CAST(`Date_time` as TIME) END))'TIMEIN2',
MIN((CASE WHEN  CAST(`Date_time` as TIME) BETWEEN '17:00:00' AND '20:00:00' THEN CAST(`Date_time` as TIME) END))'TIMEOUT2',`shiftschedule`.schedname,`shiftschedule`.salarysched 


FROM `attendancelog`
LEFT JOIN `shiftschedule` on `attendancelog`.EmpID = `shiftschedule`.chapano
GROUP BY `EmpID`, `LocID`, CAST(`Date_time` as DATE)";
```

Answer (score 0):

if you could change your table schema like this, you can simply achieve what you need

```
EmpID | CheckIn            | CheckOut          |
8636   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM AM  YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM PM
```

Comment: I think I can't change it like that  because the schedule is 4 pairs IN OUT IN OUT something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that for each employee there are always 2 records - one for check-in and one for check-out then you can go with something like this

```
SELECT check_in.EmpID, check_in.date AS CheckIn, check_out.date AS CheckOut
FROM
(SELECT @ctr := @ctr + 1 AS rownum, EmpID, date FROM timelog 
JOIN (SELECT @ctr := 0) AS tmp
WHERE status = 0
ORDER BY EmpID, date) AS check_in
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT @ctr := @ctr + 1 AS rownum, EmpID, date FROM timelog 
JOIN (SELECT @ctr := 0) AS tmp
WHERE status = 1
ORDER BY EmpID, date) AS check_out
USING (rownum)
```

But I doubt you can ensure that - there will be times when there is a CheckIn without a corresponding CheckOut and vice versa. If this is a real attendance system then the best you can do is to build a trigger which fires on INSERT and converts your `time events` (which are simple points in time) into their corresponding `time intervals of presence`. I have already done this before for a few attendance systems - contact me privately if you need further assistance.